# Is there a way that autohotkey takes the date into account?

Tags: autohotkey

Basically I need something like this:

```
x::
if (today < 2018/02/16)
send y
else
send z
return
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date = 2018/01/16
date := StrReplace(date, "/")    ; remove slashes

today = %A_Year%%A_MM%%A_DD% 

MsgBox, date =   %date%`n`ntoday = %today%

$x::
    if (today < date)
        Send y
    else
        Send z
return
```

Comment: You can either [update autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) or replace [`StrReplace`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm#function) with the depricated function [`StringReplace`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
x::
date_diff := A_Now
date_diff -= 20180216, Seconds
if (date_Diff < 0)
    msgbox, y
else
    msgbox, z
return
```